# Windows batch script to move lines from txt file to new file

Tags: windows, parsing, batch-file

I have a load of text files with some html code in them. EG:

```
Some random text....
..
...
....
<tag1>some more random text</tag1>
....
...
..
```

I need to run a script to go through each text file and *move* each line between the tags to a new text file in the same folder, and remove them from the original.

So the end result would be one file with no `<tag1>` and another file with only `<tag1>`.

I hope I made myself clear enough. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***IF*** (and that is a big, bolded, italicized, capitalized ***IF***) you can guarantee that each `<tag1>...</tag>` tag appears on a single line with no other content on that same line, and there are no tag attributes to complicate things, then the answer is easy.

***Edit*** - fixed a number of bugs, it actually works now :-)

```
@echo off
for %%F in (*.txt) do (
  echo processing %%F
  findstr /rc:"^ *<tag1>.*</tag1> *$" "%%F" >"%%~nF.tag1%%~xF"
  findstr /rvc:"^ *<tag1>.*</tag1> *$" "%%F" >"%%~nF.new%%~xF"
  >nul move /y "%%~nF.new%%~xF" "%%F"
)
```

The solution could be extended to handle tag attributes fairly easily.

But I seriously doubt your problem is really that simple. Valid HTML content can have a tag spread accross many lines, and there can be many tags on one line.

Windows native batch is pretty lousy at text processing in general, and even worse for HTML or XML. I strongly recommend getting a third party tool like gnu sed for Windows that has robust text processing. Or better yet, get a tool that is specifically designed to process HTML.

Comment: Actually, my problem really is that simple. These <tag1> lines were put in manually and they all span one line, they also have no attributes. I will try your solution right away.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. I run the .bat and nothing happens. Looks like it just hangs because I have to cancel it. I replaced *.txt with the file path/name.

Comment: @Falantar014 - Oops, that's what I get for posting code without testing. I had managed to introduce 3 bugs in 6 lines of code. The biggest problem was I forgot to specify a file in the 2nd findstr command, so it was waiting for input on stdin. All fixed now.

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks so much, works like a charm. I have pretty much zero knowledge of this but I will mess around with it some more.